# How to make one state change only after other state has been changed in functional component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (!isEditing) {
    setIsDialogOpen(false); // this happens first
  }
}, [isEditing]);

useEffect(() => {
  if (!isDialogOpen) {
    setIsEditingTool(false); // this should happen second
  }
}, [isDialogOpen]);
```

isEditing is a prop, coming from redux state. 
The Dialog Title ("Add"/"Edit") Text is shown based on isEditingTool state (being set in the second 
useState). 
The isEditing state should change only after the dialog has been closed, so that the text doesn't change before dialog close.
I have tried a lot of options (setTimeout/usePrevious hook/useLayoutEffect), but its not working. Is there any way out, the only option left would be to make separate components, which I dont want. 
Here I am using two states, setting isEditingTool only after dialog has been closed. there will be two different renders as per my understanding.

Comment: Please post a minimal [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Basically the question is, how can I change a state only after other state has been changed? The dialog title text should be changed only after the dialog has been closed. I can't copy paste the code as its on another secure system. Please let me know which part of the question is not clear. Appreciate the help.

Comment: So you want to update one state, only after another state is updated?

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented the solution here: https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-fire-xz1pt?file=/src/App.js

With hooks, we can update one state after updating another state by using useEffect.

```
export default function App() {
  const [text1, setText1] = useState("");
  const [text2, setText2] = useState("");

  // update text2, when text1 updates
  useEffect(() => {
    if (text1) {
      setText2(`${text1}, then this is text 2`);
    }
  }, [text1]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>useState callback</h1>
      <h3>{text1}</h3>
      <h4>{text2}</h4>
      <button onClick={() => setText1("this is text 1")}>Click This</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate your efforts in explaining, but this is not what I am looking for. I also came up with a non working codesand box solution (didn't have time to mock the api call). But you will get the idea. 
https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-noyce-qgrll?file=/src/App.js
I think I have fixed it (more testing needs to be done), by adding an extra state in between dialog-close state and isEditing state.
So isEditingProp -> dialogCloseState -> additionalstate -> isEditingState. Changing each one, one by one will invoke a render and in one particular render only one state will be changed.

Comment: Okay, I think I have misunderstood the question. Let me rephrase it. When the page loads, you are fetching some data from an API, which will tell whether we have to open the dialog or not?
Then if the dialog is in the open state:
We will show Add for the title because isEditingTool is initially set to false.
Now once we close the dialog we set isDialogOpen to false and once the dialog is closed we'll set isEditingTool to true.

Correct me if I am wrong somewhere.